# Installing and enabling a systemd user service for all users

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

Goal: install a systemd service, which any user should be able to start. The problem is to enable a user service (no `sudo`), as a step of installing it (with `sudo`).

I put a service file in `/etc/systemd/user/`. This requires `sudo`.

Then `sudo systemctl --user enable my_service` does not work, superuser cannot enable a service that is for users, only users can do that.

The issue:
I want to install the service as part of the `sudo make install` of my project. `sudo` is required here, in order to copy the service file to `/etc/systemd/user/` (and other things). I would like this install step to also enable the user service, so that users may start it without the need to enable it.

Solutions I can think of:

- require the installer to do an extra enable step (without sudo) after `sudo make install`,
- run the enable step as part of the install step, with `sudo -E -u $USER systemctl...`. `-E` required in order to get to `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` (needed by systemctl for users). The problem is that the install command then also needs `-E -u $USER`, which is unusual.
- require users to run `enable` on the service, if `start` fails.
- somehow drop the privileges for the `enable` step, not sure how.

It feels like this should be a usual use case, how do people normally solve this?

Answer (score 3):

#### Installing a systemd user service for all users

In order to install a systemd user service for all users, you can place your `.service` unit file in one of the folders listed in [**User Unit Search Path** in `man systemd.unit(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#User%20Unit%20Search%20Path). The important ones are:

- `/etc/systemd/user/*` (normally expected to be used for system administrators)
- `/usr/lib/systemd/user/*` (normally expected to be used by installed packages)

You will normally need `sudo`/root permissions to install these service files to these folders.

#### Enabling a systemd user service for all users

If you want to enable the service for all users, you can use the `--global` flag of systemctl, e.g. with `systemctl --global enable`, which will require `sudo`/root permissions:

> `--global`
>
> > When used with enable and disable, operate on the global user configuration directory, thus enabling or disabling a unit file globally for all future logins of all users.
>
> Taken from [`man systemctl(1)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--global)

##### Using `systemctl preset` instead of `systemctl enable`

You may want to consider using [`systemctl preset`](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Preset/) instead of `systemctl enable`. It works the same way as `systemctl enable`, unless there's a [systemd preset file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) that has a line saying `disable my-service.service`, in which case it does `systemctl disable` instead.

This lets users/admins decide whether they want your service enabled automatically. For example, Fedora has a `disable *` preset, and so all systemd services on Fedora are **not** enabled by default when installed.

---

By the way, generally systemd services aren't installed/enabled by a project's Makefile, but they're instead installed by a package manager.

For example, if you've created a `.deb` file for Debian/Ubuntu that you can `sudo apt install ./my-deb`, adding and enabling a systemd user service file is as easy as creating a file named `debian/my-package.user.service` in the package. Then [`dh_installsystemduser`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/dh_installsystemduser.1.en.html) will automatically take care of installing and enabling it, and uninstalling/disabling it when the package is installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by enabling a specific "sudo-less" command execution for all users or for specific users. The command in question is: `systemctl enable <my_service>`. After reading this and before carrying out the instructions, I encourage you to read `$ man 5 sudoers`.

This can be done in two ways:

- edit your `/etc/sudoers` with the specific command: `$ sudo visudo`. Exert CAUTION: if you botch it, you can impair your host to the point of shutting yourself out of any `sudo` access. What you will edit in is the same as what follows below.
- create a file:  `$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/my_service` whose content I detail hereafter. Note that this is as delicate as would be the direct modification of `/etc/sudoers` above. The advantage of dropping a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` over editing the `/etc/sudoers` file is that doing so create `sudo` policy modifications that are persistent throughout `sudoers` system updates.

The content to edit in is:

```
ALL <your_host_name>=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl enable <my_service>
```

In this case it enables `ALL` (users) to issue (and execute) the command on host `<your_host_name>` without the need to use `sudo`.

If you want to do so for only one user, just replace `ALL` by that user name. If it is neither (i.e. not `ALL` and not one user name but several), create a user alias to bunch up the user names that will have the privilege to issue the sudo-less cmd. In that case your one added line becomes two:

```
User_Alias <systserv_enable_users> = Kamela, bkd12, Oliver, Gauthier
<systserv_enable_users> <your_host_name>=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl enable <my_service>
```

If you decide to add this line or these lines directly to `/etc/sudoers`, do so ABOVE the line that reads:

```
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, great effort! The strange thing for me was that `sudo` is required to write the user service file, but `sudo` cannot enable it. So, I cannot do both in a single `sudo make install`. What would need to be enabled is `sysmtectl --user`, for `sudo`. (in this case, I think that systemctl was not appropriate for what we were trying to do. But the question remains: how to install a user service in one step?)

Comment: @Gauthier: ***Installation in one step***: please, show us what you tried ! This community can help you with concrete issues. This is not a free scripting service. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Gauthier: In my answer, I merely focused on the one well-defined problem you described in the second part of your post: how to give users with no `sudo` privilege access to cmd execution that normally requires `sudo` privilege. You commented: "The strange thing for me was `sudo` is required to write the user service file, but `sudo` cannot enable it. " Not sure I get why it is strange. Writing a service unit file is a task normally reserved for users w/ admin privilege. It consumes resources and enabling a daemon may have consequences. Only a few users should be trusted to enable it ...

Comment: it is the other way around, as stated in the question: "superuser cannot enable a service that is for users, only users can do that". All users can enable it, but `sudo` cannot. I am aware of how to let users do sudo stuff without the full privilege, but here it's the opposite. I've shown my try, running part of the install as user instead of sudo (`sudo -E -u $USER`), and it works, but it felt unnatural and dirty, hence asking the question.

Comment: @Gauthier: Glad to see you have no issue. `sudo` **is meant** to execute a command as another user, hence the restricted access policy to it by default in most *nix distribution. There is absolutely nothing "_unnatural and dirty"_ in using `sudo -E -u $USER <cmd [cmd_args]>`.